# How to use repository method findByxx about field name with underline(_) in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

```
// This is my entity class object
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class PayOrder {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=true)
     */
    private $pay_no;
};
// I use it in my function, this is the Repository
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Exception;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;
class PayOrderRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {
    public function get( PayOrder $payOrder ) {
        $pay_no=$payOrder->getPayNo();
        // It will occurs a exception, how to fix it, any one can help me?
        return $this->findBypayno($pay_no);
    }
};
```

Besides that, I can't find the document to fix the problem.
 I want to use the field name `pay_no`, and I want to use the repository
findbyxxx, but I do not how to use it correctly.

Comment: camel case is strongly recommended, why not to use it?

Comment: Anyway. I don't think it would work that way, you can create custom repository method for this particular request

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I also debug the code right here ,exactly symfony change the real field name right here,
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/e2189307f45c3decdc396026664901b46d7fac24/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L259

i have situation right now ,the url will post the data which  name is "pay_no" ,
and i build a form with PayOrder class,by the way, the database column field name is pay_no too,and now ,
what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I also debug the code right here ,exactly symfony change the real field name right here,
[link](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/e2189307f45c3decdc396026664901b46d7fac24/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L259)

i have situation right now ,the url will post the data which  name is "pay_no" ,
and i build a form with PayOrder class,by the way, the database column field name is pay_no too,and now ,
what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just use

```
$this->findBy(['pay_no' => $payOrder->getPayNo());
```

The `findByX` method are just intercepted method calls - see [line up 177 to 179](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/e2189307f45c3decdc396026664901b46d7fac24/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L177-L179) that are transformed to `findBy` calls.

Comment: thank you for your answer!i also debug the code right here ,exactly symfony change the real field name right here,https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/e2189307f45c3decdc396026664901b46d7fac24/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L259

i have situation right now ,the url will post the name is  pay_no ,and i build a form with PayOrder class,by the way, the database column field name is pay_no too,and now ,what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: As Mert suggests in the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935493/1123614) I would change the field to payNo. Can you please be more specific about your question with the form? I don't know what you mean exactly.

Comment: yes ,but i do not known which i should tell more the specific, the question about that ,which point are you not clear?

Comment: I don't understand the issue with the url and the form but here is what I would do: 
1. Change the PayOrder field to `$payNo`
2. Update the Form to use payNo. If you want to use "pay_no" in the html form you can name the form field "pay_no" and then use the form option `'property_path' => 'payNo'`

Comment: thank you very much !
I think use property_path is ok,but there will generate another problem,the form will lose PayOrder field to $payNo validation when the form->handleRequest($request),and  call the form->isvalid(),it will be miss the part of $payNo's validation.

Answer (score 2):

Change your property name to `$payNo`.

Probably in your entity look like that;

```
//...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
$pay_no

//....
```

Change it like that;

```
//...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="pay_no", type="string", length=255)
 */
$payNo

//....
```

After that,

1. Remove old getter/setter for `$pay_no`
2. For Symfony2 run `app/console doctrine:generate:entities`
3. For Symfony4 run `bin/console make:entity --regenerate`

Goodluck. If you have any question or blocker please write me.